# Create a view that shows from which table content comes

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a little problem with a postgreSQL view I have to create for a school project.

I have five tables named:

- Input(inputId , distributorId , date)
- Inputline(InputId, ObjectId, ammount)
- Output(outputId, clientId, date)
- Outputline(outputId, ObjectId, ammount)
- Stock(ObjectId, ammount)

Now I need a view which shows me the changes (per objectId) made in chronological order like this:

```
| Date       | type   | ammount In | ammount out |
+------------+--------+------------+-------------+
| 10-10-2007 | Input  | 10         |             |
| 11-10-2007 | Output |            | 5           |
| 12-10-2007 | Input  | 20         |             |
```

I have absolutely no clue on how to do this so I would really appreciate your help.
If more details are needed, don't hesitate to ask =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT o.date, 'Output' AS type, ol.amount AS amount_out, NULL AS amount_in
FROM   outputline ol
JOIN   output     o USING (outputid)

UNION ALL
SELECT i.date, 'Input', NULL, il.amount
FROM   inputline il
JOIN   input     i USING (inputid)
ORDER  BY date, type;
```

The `ORDER BY` clause after a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` applies to the whole result set.

I order by `type` additionally to break ties with the date, so that input comes before output.

Answer (score 0):

A view is more a combination of data from other tables rather than new information. I recommend using a new table to show the changes and then either using [triggers](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/triggers.html) or if you are inserting/updating/etc data for your tables through stored procedures then just adding the insertion into your changes table through the procedure. Triggers are placed on your tables For example an 'on insert' trigger on your outputline table that does an action (insertion in this case) on another table (changes table).

Comment: This would be good if he was tracking the changes to tables, but the OP already has the necessary reporting tables to assemble this information.

Comment: True. Thanks. I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select "date", type, "amount in", "amount out"
from (
    select 'output' as "type", "date", amount as "amount out", 0 as "amount in"
    from outputline
    union all
    select 'input' as "type", "date", 0 as "amount out", amount as "amount in"
    from inputline
) s
order by "date"
```

Comment: hmm, I think you are on the right path there, but "date" is not a column in outpuline and inputline, only in output, and input